# calculation conditional on the signs of an element in r

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I know the question is silly but I really can't solve it. I just want to do different operations to the elements in a dataframe deppending on its sign. The following code generating a mock dataframe:

```
mock<-data.frame(matrix(NA,ncol=5,nrow=2))
colnames(mock)<-as.vector(c("m","n","1985-02-04","1985-02-05","1985-02-06"))

rownames(mock)<-as.vector(c("fund1","fund2"))
mock
mock[1,]<-c(0.001,0.0045,-0.03,0.25,NA)
mock[2,]<-c(0.004,0.0004,NA,0.12,-0.087)
mock
```

so it looks like

```
         m      n     1985-02-04 1985-02-05 1985-02-06
fund1 0.001 0.0045      -0.03       0.25         NA
fund2 0.004 0.0004         NA       0.12     -0.087
```

for each fund, m and n represent two different ratios, the last three figures are returns on the given days. I wish to do the following oerations:

if the return x on one day is positive, I need (x+m)/(1+n) to replace the corresponding figure in the dataframe. 
If the return x is negative, I need x+m to replace the corresponding figure in the dataframe. 
If it is NA on the day, I will leave it NA.

I tried the following code:

```
 Grossreturn<-function(x){
  a<-x[3:5]
  m<-x[1]
  p<-x[2]

  a[a>0]<-(a[a>0]+m)/(1-p)
  a[a<0]<-a[a<0]+m
  return(a)
}

apply(mock,1,Grossreturn)
```

and of course it failed and the error message is:

```
Error in a[a > 0] <- (a[a > 0] + m)/(1 - p) : 
  NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments
```

I really get stucked here and couldn't sort it out. Can someone help?

Thanks!

Comment: This question isn't silly, but it is very challenging :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should just exclude NAs from all your assignments.  A sample syntax for doing this is below:

```
> foo = data.frame(x=runif(3)-0.5, y=runif(3))  #random data frame
> foo[2,1] <- NA  #adding an NA
> foo
           x         y
1 -0.4616014 0.4892859
2         NA 0.4730237
3  0.4060813 0.1517448
```

If you now try to reassign without filtering out NAs, you get your error.

```
> foo[sign(foo$x)==-1, 1] <- -10
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, sign(foo$x) == -1, 1, value = -10) : 
  missing values are not allowed in subscripted assignments of data frames
```

But not if you explicitly leave out NAs:

```
> foo[sign(foo$x)==-1 & !is.na(foo$x), 1] <- -10
> foo
            x         y
1 -10.0000000 0.4892859
2          NA 0.4730237
3   0.4060813 0.1517448
```

Comment: Why not?  The title of the post is "calculation conditional on the signs of an element in r" and the only question inside is "Can someone help?".  What do you think the question is?

Answer (score -1):

Here is a code which solves your problem:

```
grossreturn <- function(x) {
  m <- x[1]
  n <- x[2]

  # iterate over all date columns and compute new value
  for (i in 3:length(x)) {
     if (is.na(x[i]) {
                                    # NA remains NA
     } else if (x[i] < 0) {
       x[i] <- x[i] + m             # x + m
     } else {
       # x[i] >= 0
       # includes case where x[i] == 0
       x[i] <- (x[i] + m) / (1 + n) # (x + m) / (1 + n)
     }
  }

  return x
}

result <- apply(mock, 1, FUN=function(x) grossreturn(x))
```

I wanted to use an `apply` function to iterate over the numerical columns after extracting out `m` and `n`, but there does not seem to be any vectorized `apply` functions which can also pass multiple parameters as input (so `mapply` would not be a vectorized solution).

I assumed that the case where a return is 0 that you wanted (x + m) / (1 + n).  Also, you test whether `R` drops either the row or column names when you run this code.